# Accessにリンクを張ったSQLserverのテーブルに更新クエリをかけたが『更新可能なクエリであることが必要です』と出る。

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

MicrosoftAccess2019を使用して、AzureのSqlServerに接続しています。
Access側にリンクテーブルを設置し、そこに『UPDATE』を行おうとしているのですが、
『更新可能なクエリであることが必要です』というエラーが出てしまいます。

しかし、一切INNER JOIN などの結合は行っていない単一テーブルであり、Accessの
ローカルテーブルの時はこのエラーは出ませんでした。

以下がクエリです。

```
UPDATE [T_estmain] SET [price] = 262144 WHERE [prop_id] = 187 AND [est_categoly] = 4 AND [nsme] = '材料費' AND [unit_id] = 2
```

尚、このT_estmainのテーブルには、キーは一切設定していません。
Nullも重複も許している、単純なテーブルです。

原因と対策をお教えください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

公式に書いてあるところが見つからなかったのですが
Accessでリンクテーブルを更新するには、そのリンクテーブルの行を一意に特定できることが必要です

主キーがあればそれでよいのですが、そうでない場合
T_estmainにrowversion(timestamp)型の項目を追加して、リンク時にそれを一意にする項目として指定すれば更新できるようになります

Comment: ありがとうございました。ご指摘いただいた方法で、更新できるようになりました。これからも何かありましたら宜しくお願いいたします。